# javascript if- else statement Dose't work

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have made 2 simple php pages with every page has table. In the table about 15 input fields.
example

```
<tr><td>Huur</td><td><input class="vast_lasten" type="text" name="Huur" /></td></tr>

<tr><td>Roken</td><td><input class="vast_lasten" type="text" name="Roken"/></td></tr>
```

i calculate all the input field together.

```
<tr><td>Total</td><td><input  type="text" id="total1" name="total1" value="0" /></td></tr>
```

i get the total without any problem wat i want to do is if statement in 3 page something like result.
but i couldn't get it work that is the javaScript code that i used onlt the if statement doesn't work the rest does.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var VastInkomen = 0;
$('.txtBox').keyup(function(){
$('.txtBox').each(function() {
var txtBoxVal = $(this).val();
    VastInkomen = VastInkomen + Number(txtBoxVal);
});
$('#VastInkomen').val(VastInkomen);
    VastInkomen = 0;
});

var vastLasten = 0;
$('.vast_lasten').keyup(function(){
$('.vast_lasten').each(function() {
var vastLastenVal = $(this).val();
    vastLasten = vastLasten + Number(vastLastenVal);
});
$('#vastLasten').val(vastLasten);
    vastLasten = 0;
});
    if(VastInkomen  > vastLasten){
        document.write("total is bigger so you are save");
    }
else if(VastInkomen  < vastLasten){
    document.write("total1 is bigger you have a probleam");
}


});
```

Any suggestion will be great.

Comment: `else is`? That's a type there, it's supposed to be `else if`

Comment: Also why do you have a semicolon in the end of the logical operator?

Comment: Hi, Tareq thanks for the replay. i removed the semicolon but still doesn't work

Comment: Don't use `document.write` use `console.log` instead

Comment: + you have nothing if VastInkomen === vastLasten

Comment: `$('.txtBox').keyup(function(){` when there's no field with `txtBox` class

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have used else is, instead else if, as it was mentioned, however you can use logical operator as well which make your code much easier to read:

const comparison = (VastInkomen  > vastLasten) ? "total is bigger so you are save":"total1 is bigger you have a problem";
    document.write(comparison);

Comment: when i use the logical operator and the short if statement. i get direct the message .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var vastInkomen = 0;
$('.txtBox').keyup(function () {
    vastInkomen = 0;
    $('.txtBox').each(function () {
        var txtBoxVal = $(this).val();
        vastInkomen += Number(txtBoxVal);
    });
    $('#vastInkomen').val(vastInkomen);
    writeResult();
});

var vastLasten = 0;
$('.vast_lasten').keyup(function () {
    vastLasten = 0;
    $('.vast_lasten').each(function () {
        var vastLastenVal = $(this).val();
        vastLasten += Number(vastLastenVal);
    });
    $('#vastLasten').val(vastLasten);
    writeResult();
});

function writeResult() {

    if (vastInkomen !== 0 && vastLasten !== 0) {
        if (vastInkomen > vastLasten) {
            var result1 = vastInkomen - vastLasten;

            $('#result').text("Content " + result1 );

        } else if (vastInkomen < vastLasten) {
            var result = vastLasten - vastInkomen;
            $('#result').text(" content - " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

});